# how to fix paint component not invoking paintComponent?

Tags: java, swing

I looked through some of the other questions similar to mine, but none of them seemed of help when i tried their fixes, How would i go about fixing this as its the only thing stopping my programme from printing rectangles which is vital.

Below is the code for the entire programme as im not sure in where the problem lies, only what the problem is. The stuff that is commented I'm currently not using, but I'm keeping it in there just in case I find a use for it later on. Many thanks

Currently, my programme does not draw any sort of rectangle as it should, and its because repaint doesn't invoke the paintcomponent. My question is basically asking as to why nothing is printed when I start it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

/**
* Write a description of class Game here.
* 
* @author Adam Steele 
* @version 1.0.0
*/
public class Game extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
// logger
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName());

// variables
private boolean isGolden; // Class wide boolean for whether rectangle is golden
private int score; // Stores the score
private int noOfAttempts; // stores number of rectangles that are created
private int goldTimer; // attempts before fail & new rectangle is created

// graphics
private Rectangle box;
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;

// testing
private ArrayList<Rect> rects = new ArrayList<Rect>();


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Game
 */
public Game()
{
    setup();
}

public void setup()
{
    LOGGER.info("setup has been called");

    // initalise frame
    frame = new JFrame();
    final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
    final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;

    // set frame attributes
    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setTitle("Gold Picker");

    // initalise panel
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.addMouseListener(this);
    // add things to panel - ie. score, time limit, etc.
    // panel.add();

    JLabel amLabel = new JLabel("I am a GUI label.");
    panel.add(amLabel);
    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    button.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    button.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    panel.add(button);

    // add panel to frame
    frame.add(panel);

    // Make frame visible
    showFrame();

    LOGGER.info("Game window has been created");

    // (re)set variables
    score = 0;
    noOfAttempts = 0;
    goldTimer = 30;

    // this is to check variable initalisation
    LOGGER.info("Variables have been initalised at: score = " + score + ", noOfAttempts = " + noOfAttempts + ", goldTimer = " + goldTimer);  

    // start game
    decideGolden();
}

public void showFrame()
{
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * A method that decides if the rectangle will be golden based on a random chance
 */
public void decideGolden()
{
    double goldProportion = Math.random() * 1;
    double goldChance = Math.random() * 1;
    //System.out.println(goldChance + " " + goldProportion);
    if(goldChance <= goldProportion) {
        isGolden = true;
    } else {
        isGolden = false;
    }

    LOGGER.info("isGolden has been set to " + isGolden);

    timedRect();
}

/**
 * Method for generating rectangled on timed intervals 
 */
public void timedRect()
{

    /*
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {

        }
    }, 20000, 20000 );
    /*
    if(isGolden) {
        repaint();
    } else {
        createNormalRectangle();
    }


    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    }, 
    20000); */

    LOGGER.info("timedRect has been called");

    for(int i = 0; i < goldTimer; i++) {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("try has been reached");
            //repaint();
            drawRectangle();
            Thread.sleep(20000); // wait 20 seconds..
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g); 

    LOGGER.info("paintComponent has been called with " + g);
    /*
    int x = 400;
    int y = 300;
    // Using Math.random() or .nextInt() we could make random gold rects
    int width = 100;
    int height = 100; 

    LOGGER.info("x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", width = " + width + ", height = " + height);

    if(isGolden) {
            //g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100); // g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
    } else {
            //g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
    }
    */

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for(Rect rectangle : rects) { // for each Rect object in rect ArrayList .. 
        rectangle.paint(g2d);
    }

} 

/**
 * 
 */
public void drawRectangle()
{

    int x = (int) (Math.random() * getWidth());
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * getHeight());
    int width = (int) (Math.random() * (getWidth() / 4));
    int height = (int) (Math.random() * (getHeight() / 4));
   // LOGGER.info("x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", width = " + width + ", height = " + height);




    if (x + width > getWidth()) {
        x = getWidth() - width;
    }

    if (y + height > getHeight()) {
        y = getHeight() - height;
    }

    Color color = new Color(
            (int) (Math.random() * 255),
            (int) (Math.random() * 255),
            (int) (Math.random() * 255));

    rects.add(new Rect(x, y, width, height, color));

   repaint();
   // LOGGER.info("repaint has been called, check if paintComponent has been called..");
} 

/** 
 * these methods are needed to override the MouseListener 
 * ..and hence needed to implement the MouseListener
 * ..which will probably only be used for testing
 * ..actionlistener maybe more appropriate
*/ 

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    LOGGER.info("Mouse has been clicked");

    drawRectangle();
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

}
```

Rect class in case its needed

```
Rect class
import java.awt.*;

/**
* Deaals with misc properties of rect
* Inherits the Rectangle class from java.awt.Rectangle
public class Rect extends Rectangle
{
private Color color;

 /**
 * Constructor for objects of class Rect
 */
public Rect(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color)
{
    super(x, y, width, height);
    this.color = color;
}

public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) 
{
    g2d.setColor(color);
    g2d.fill(this);
}
}
```

Comment: Please tell us more about the problem itself that you're having. Your question does not tell us any of this, and you don't want folks to make wild guesses or completely ignore your question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels hi I edited the post to try explain more about my question, but I don't know to word it differently than I already have

Comment: Seems to work okay for me, given the fact that I don't have your `Rect` class or any idea how `drawRectangle` is called, I had to guess ... a fully runnable example, which demonstrates your problem would be more useful

Comment: @MadProgrammer what did you use to make it work? Ill update my post so the whole code I have written is shown for you

Comment: @TylerH You never add `Game` to anything which could paint it, Swing's not dumb, if you component is never displayed, it will never paint it - `Game` should NOT be creating the frame, that's not its responsibility, instead, create and manage the frame separately

Comment: @TylerH I'd also take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) - it'll be better then your current `for-loop`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean? So is it a simple error that's easily fixed?

Comment: @TylerH `Game` is a `JPanel`, you've overidden it's `paintComponent` method because you want to do some custom painting, BUT, you never actually add this to anything which can display it, so it will never be painted

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you never actually add `Game` to anything which can display it, therefore it will never be painted.

Before a component can be painted, it must be added to a container which is realised on the screen.

One of the issues you're having is your `Game` class is taking on to much responsibility, it should be focused on displaying and managing the game state, not also creating the basic UI.

Another issue you're going to have is your `timedRect` method will block the EDT, preventing anything from getting painted anyway

This is a "basic" example (I've not tested it because I don't have your `Rect` class), but conceptually it should get you closer to your goal.

Realistically, I'd have a separate "main" class which started the app, setup the initial state, created the UI and gets the ball rolling.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import org.w3c.dom.css.Rect;

public class Game extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LOGGER.info("setup has been called");

                // initalise frame
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
                final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;

                // set frame attributes
                frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
                frame.setTitle("Gold Picker");

                // initalise panel
                JPanel panel = new Game();
                // add things to panel - ie. score, time limit, etc.
                // panel.add();

                JLabel amLabel = new JLabel("I am a GUI label.");
                panel.add(amLabel);
                JButton button = new JButton("Button");
                button.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                button.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                panel.add(button);

                // add panel to frame
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                LOGGER.info("Game window has been created");
            }
        });
    }
// logger

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName());

// variables
    private boolean isGolden; // Class wide boolean for whether rectangle is golden
    private int score; // Stores the score
    private int noOfAttempts; // stores number of rectangles that are created
    private int goldTimer; // attempts before fail & new rectangle is created

    private int gameLoops = 0;

// graphics
    private Rectangle box;

// testing
    private ArrayList<Rect> rects = new ArrayList<Rect>();

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Game
     */
    public Game() {
        addMouseListener(this);
        // (re)set variables
        score = 0;
        noOfAttempts = 0;
        goldTimer = 30;

        // this is to check variable initalisation
        LOGGER.info("Variables have been initalised at: score = " + score + ", noOfAttempts = " + noOfAttempts + ", goldTimer = " + goldTimer);

        decideGolden();
    }

    /**
     * A method that decides if the rectangle will be golden based on a random
     * chance
     */
    public void decideGolden() {
        double goldProportion = Math.random() * 1;
        double goldChance = Math.random() * 1;
        //System.out.println(goldChance + " " + goldProportion);
        if (goldChance <= goldProportion) {
            isGolden = true;
        } else {
            isGolden = false;
        }

        LOGGER.info("isGolden has been set to " + isGolden);

        timedRect();
    }

    /**
     * Method for generating rectangled on timed intervals
     */
    public void timedRect() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (gameLoops < goldTimer) {
                    LOGGER.info("try has been reached");
                    //repaint();
                    drawRectangle();
                    gameLoops++;
                } else {
                    ((Timer) (e.getSource())).stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
        LOGGER.info("timedRect has been called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        LOGGER.info("paintComponent has been called with " + g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (Rect rectangle : rects) { // for each Rect object in rect ArrayList .. 
            rectangle.paint(g2d);
        }

    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public void drawRectangle() {

        int x = (int) (Math.random() * getWidth());
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * getHeight());
        int width = (int) (Math.random() * (getWidth() / 4));
        int height = (int) (Math.random() * (getHeight() / 4));
        // LOGGER.info("x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", width = " + width + ", height = " + height);

        if (x + width > getWidth()) {
            x = getWidth() - width;
        }

        if (y + height > getHeight()) {
            y = getHeight() - height;
        }

        Color color = new Color(
                (int) (Math.random() * 255),
                (int) (Math.random() * 255),
                (int) (Math.random() * 255));

        rects.add(new Rect(x, y, width, height, color));

        repaint();
        LOGGER.info("repaint has been called, check if paintComponent has been called..");
    }

    /**
     * these methods are needed to override the MouseListener ..and hence needed
     * to implement the MouseListener ..which will probably only be used for
     * testing ..actionlistener maybe more appropriate
     */
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        LOGGER.info("Mouse has been clicked");

        drawRectangle();
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public class Rect extends Rectangle {

        private Color color;

        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class Rect
         */
        public Rect(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
            super(x, y, width, height);
            this.color = color;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fill(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey man, here's the code I'm using for my rect class if this helps in anyway, but I managed to get your code implemented into mine yet now it doesn't even show a canvas / any rectangles being shown still. I'm assuming my next fix lies within my rect class? My rect class will be in the main post at the bottom if its needed

Comment: Sorry, my bad, `repaint` was commented out in the `drawRectangle` method ... don't know why, but I've updated and tested it now

Comment: hey I added my rect class into the original post, it still doesn't seem to paint anything and I cant seem to find out why

Comment: @TylerH I've update the example to be self contained and works find for me

Answer (score 0):

Why are you extending JPanel when you have an instance of JPanel? When you extend a class, you inherit all of its functionality.
Instead of using your instance "panel.add" whatever, get rid of your JPanel instance and use this.add.

Which leads to my next statement:
Your class should extend JComponent, you're not overriding paintcomponent because JPanel doesn't have a paintcomponent() method to override.

Read up on how to properly implement JComponent and JFrame and how they go together. Normally you add all your drawings to the JComponent, then you say frame.add(component), where component is of type JComponent.

Try reimplementing your code in this fashion and seperate your classes, now you don't have to follow this exact format but from what you've posted, I think you're lost.

1. Implement a class that extends JFrame, this will be your frame.
2. Implement a class that "knows" how to draw your rectangle shapes. You must put it in a method called draw(Graphics2D g2){}.
3. Implement a class that extends JComponent, this class may have an arraylist of your "rectangle" objects.

   ```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
       // initialize your rectangle objects here
       for(Rectangles rects: whateveryourarraylistvariable) {
           rects.draw(g2);
       }
   }
   ```

good luck

Comment: *"Which leads to my next statement: Your class should extend JComponent, you're not overriding paintcomponent because JPanel doesn't have a paintcomponent() method to override."* - What do you think `JPanel` extends from? There's also a very good reason why `paintComponent` is `protected` by default, making it `public` is unwise as, frankly, no one should ever call it directly